# C++ pointer address issue

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

```
int *i = new int;
cout << &i << endl << i;
delete i;
i = 0;
```

i get this output:

0031FB2B

0057C200

Why 2 different addresses? Isn't & referencing the address of the dynamic pointer and i itself the address of the pointer, which should be the same address?

Comment: I think i sort of get it. Thanks man. And wow to this community.

Comment: Any downvoter cares to explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&i` is the address of the pointer.  This is the place where the value returned by `new` will be stored.  `i` is the value of the pointer itself, this is the value returned by `new`.

And just for completeness, *i is the value of the integer pointed to, which at the moment is uninitialized, but this is where your actual data will go.